# Jackson - deserialize one base enums

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

is it possible to deserialize enums, which have a one based index?

```
enum Status {
  Active,
  Inactive
}
```

{status:1} means Status.Active, but Jackson makes it Status.Inactive :(

Comment: The question has nothing to do with serialization

Comment: Like Oscar says, enumeration (and computer science in general) is 0-based. Subtract 1 from the number if it's something you're receiving from another layer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a custom type deserialiser for your enum:

```
public enum Status {
    ACTIVE,
    INACTIVE;
    public static Status fromTypeCode(final int typeCode) {
        switch(typeCode) {
        case 1: return ACTIVE;
        case 2: return INACTIVE;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Status type code: " + typeCode);
    }
}

public class StatusDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Status> {
    @Override
    public Status deserialize(final JsonParser parser, final DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return Status.fromTypeCode(parser.getValueAsInt());
    }
}
```

You can then tell Jackson to use your custom deserialiser for a property:

```
public class WarpDrive {
    private Status status; 
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StatusDeserializer.class)
    public void setStatus(final Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
}
```

You can also configure the Jackson object mapper to use your custom deserialiser for all occurrences of the target type. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers.

Answer (score 49):

```
public enum Status {
ACTIVE(1),
INACTIVE(2);
private final int value;
Status(int v) {
    value = v;
}
@org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonValue
public int value() {
    return value;
}  
@org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator
public static Status fromValue(int typeCode) {
    for (Status c: Status.values()) {
        if (c.value==typeCode) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Status type code: " + typeCode);        

}}
```

Comment: This is actually a simpler, more idiomatic solution than mine. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is also a great way to handle a common problem of enumerations being serialized with unknown capitalization.

Comment: but if enum is third party ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow you can use Jackson mixins.

Answer (score 2):

Enums have numeric *ordinals*, starting in zero, and get assigned to each value in an enumeration in the order in which they were declared. For example, in your code `Active` has ordinal `0` and `Inactive` has ordinal `1`. You can go back and forth between the value of an enum and its ordinal, like this:

```
// ordinal=0, since Active was declared first in the enum
int ordinal = Status.Active.ordinal();

// enumVal=Active, since 0 is the ordinal corresponding to Active
Status enumVal = Status.values()[0];
```

Clearly the ordinal `1` corresponds to `Inactive` (it's not a Jackson problem), as explained above, ordinals in an enumeration are zero-based. Maybe you should fix your code to reflect that, and make sure that `{status:0}` means `Status.Active`.

Comment: Its clear, that 0 means Status.Active in the java world! But its not my api, I'm only implementing a client. And the api say's that 1 means Active and 2 Inactive. So my question was, if I can make Jackson knowing about this.

Perhaps by simply adding a dummy value for shifting the ordinal by one.

Comment: It is not recommended to use Enum ordinals, much less using them in serialization, because changes to the Enum definition may change the ordinal numbers.

Comment: imho this answer does not answer the question