# How to create Enum of operators >, <, <=, >=

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, enums

I simply want to create enum of operators like this but this gives errors.

```
Public enum MyOperators {"<", "<=", ">",  ">="}
```

From suggestion on SO , i tried something like this.

```
Public enum MyOperators {
  Less ='<', 
  LessOrEqual = '<=',
  Greater = '>', 
  GreaterOrEqual = '>='
}
```

Now it does not like the '=' sign in LessOrEqual and GreaterOrEqual.

You can see how MS approaches it at MS references [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Filter/Operators.cs,a7919ed5ee0d116b) for c# operators. 
I can do that as well but i just wanted to see if there is any better suggestion.

**EDIT**

If you can make this work without a list and switch statement you would answer my question

```
        enum MyOperators {"<", "<=", ">",  ">="}

        string s  = Console.ReadLine();
        MyOperators op;

        if (Enum.TryParse(s, true, out op)) {
            //user entered operator 
        }
        else {
            //not operator
        }
```

Comment: single quotes are for Char double quotes for Strings just fyi

Comment: The `char` approach will somewhat work, but you can't do `'<='` as a character literal because "<" and "=" are two different characters, and would be like trying to assign a value of 5 and 15 to an integer variable at the same time. The string approach will just straight up not work, and you are SOL on that front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An enum value is typically of type `int`. Consequently, you connot assign objects of type `string` or `char`. You may misunderstand the concept of an enum and when to use it.

As [Abion47](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255873/abion47) said: "... An enum type can be declared to be any native integral type from `byte` to `ulong` and everything in between. [...] This does not include `char`. [...] `char` is implicitly convertible to `int`, so you can assign an integer enum to a character literal."

You appear to look for a list of constants. As I don't know what you want to do with your "enum" try this, it may help:

```
public static class MyOperators
{
    public const string Less = "<"; 
    public const string LessOrEqual = "<=";
    public const string Greater = ">";
    public const string GreaterOrEqual = ">=";
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence isn't *entirely* accurate. An `enum` type can be declared to be any native integral type from `byte` to `ulong` and everything in between. True to your point, though, this does not include `char`. (Of course, `char` is implicitly convertible to `int`, so you _can_ assign an integer enum to a character literal.)

Comment: You can not mark const as static. It is static by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Per your edit, you can easily provide that functionality with a list, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't want one. For example, you can do this:

```
var operators = new List<string>() { "<", "<=", ">", ">=" };

string s  = Console.ReadLine();

if (operators.Contains(s))
{
    //user entered operator 
}
else
{
    //not operator
}
```

You could even substitute the list for an array, if you so choose.

Comment: This is acceptable way to do it if you are dealing with small list. But if you have lets say 100+ operators this approach is not good - from easy to read, document-able code perspective. @QualityCatalyst answer is the better approach.

Comment: @Davvit I'd actually disagree. If you store the values as constants and need to see if a string value is equal to one of them, you would have to compare the value to each constant individually. Either that, or you would need to arrange them all into a list/array anyway. QualityCatalist's approach is better for storing the values, but this is better for comparing them, which is what OP is ultimately trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551699) how this is possible using the EnumMember attribute, if you are primarily concerned with deserializing something like JSON:

```
public enum CardType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "<")]
    LessThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "<=")]
    LessThanEqualTo,
    [EnumMember(Value = ">")]
    GreaterThan,
    [EnumMember(Value = ">=")]
    GreaterThanEqualTo
}
```

Comment: must be newer feature. i was on .net 4 when i was trying to do this.