# Enum value doesn't show EnumMember value on razor page ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, datatables, razor-pages

I have a Razor page and on that page I show data in a JavaScript datatable. I tried to show enum value as a string, but I don't get the correct string representation for my enum value.

**Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
```

**Enums.cs**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum Operation
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "None")]
    None,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Send e-mail")]
    SendEmail,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Download file")]
    DownloadFile
}
```

**Result.cs**

```
public class Result
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "smallint")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
        public Operation Operation { get; set; }

        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }
```

**ResultPage**

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
     var resultData = _dbContext.Results.ToList();

     var jsonData = new {recordsTotal = resultData.Count(), data = resultData
};

     return new JsonResult(jsonData);
}
```

**ResultView**
Here is just script for JS datatable

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#resultDatatable').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "/Result",
                type: 'POST',
                headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': $('@Html.AntiForgeryToken()').val() }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true, "visible": false},
                {
                    "data": "startDate", "name": "Start date", "autoWidth": true, "render": function (d) {
                        return moment(d).format("YYYY/MM/DD");}
                },
                {
                    "data": "endDate", "name": "End date", "autoWidth": true, "render": function(d) {
                        return moment(d).format("YYYY/MM/DD");}
                },
                { "data": "operation", "name": "Operation", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "success", "name": "Success", "autoWidth": true }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I call this I get the correct enum representation from the EnumMember value:

```
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultData); //SendEmail -> "Send e-mail"
```

But, when I:

```
return new JsonResult(resultData);      //SendEmail -> "SendEMail"
```

I tried with this solution [ASP.NET MVC Core API Serialize Enums to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096102/asp-net-mvc-core-api-serialize-enums-to-string) but I don't get the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 hours struggling I found that:

*Serialization of enums as strings is supported by System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter, however renaming via attributes is not implemented.*

So I used accepted answer from this link, where I used NewtosoftJson instead built in System.Text.Json.

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson(option =>
            {
                option.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                option.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

Also I applied attribute over enum `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Operation
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "None")]
    None,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Send e-mail")]
    SendEmail,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Download file")]
    DownloadFile
}
```

Now I have expected enum string value on my page.

[deserialize json with array of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59998747/deserialize-json-with-array-of-enum)