# Return all products with Enum value using [HttpGet] in AspNet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, http-get

How is it possible to use the `string` value of an `Enum` to return all objects with a parameter that matches?

With this **Enum** for **Language** and `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` in the Class:

```cs
public enum Lcid
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "en-US")]en_US,
    [EnumMember(Value = "en-AU")]en_AU
}
```

And another class that holds the Enum value like so:

```cs
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public Lcid Lcid { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried constructing a **HttpGet** method like:

```cs
[HttpGet("lcid/{lcid}")]
public async Task<ActionResult><IEnumerable<Application>>> GetApplicationByLcid([FromRoute]string lcid)
{
    var applications = _context.Application.Where(a => a.Language.ToString() == lcid);
    if (applications.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await applications.ToListAsync();
}
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work.

I have also tried to use additional code within the `GetApplicationByLcid` method:

```cs
[HttpGet("lcid/{lcid}")]
public async Task<ActionResult><IEnumerable<Application>>> GetApplicationByLcid([FromRoute]string lcid)
{

    int ValueToFind = Lcid["lcid"];

    var applications = _context.Application.Where(a => a.Lcid == ValueToFind);
    if (applications.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return await applications.ToListAsync();
}
```

That doesn't work either. I have been trying to work this out using just a basic CLI application without much luck either. I would have to know the value of the string and convert it out using a switch statement in CLI testing:

```cs
public static int x;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string lcid = "en-US";

    switch(lcid)
    {
        case "en-AU":
            x = (int)Lcid.en_AU;

            break;
        case "en-US":
            x = (int)Lcid.en_US;
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

This would return `0`, but it's a lot of code to just get the value, and I'd still have to be able to index that against all the `Application` object in my DB that have the Enum value there.

In `Program.cs` I have enabled Enum to convert the output to **string** by adding:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => 
{
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

Could my original code be re-written so to show how to find all `Application` object that have a specific **Lcid** value for Lcid from the Enum?

Comment: Lcid class definition, please? because your Aplication class didn't have any Languaje on it

Comment: @J.Salas I have used the word `Language` and `Lcid` inter-operably when typing my example. I have updated it to use the single term `Lcid`

Comment: Was the problem resolved? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little problem with hyphen and underscore conversion, thats because Custom Attriubutes are not easily accessed.
The 'hacky' way to achieve it is simply

```
var applications = _context.Application.Where(a => a.Language.ToString().Replace("_","-") == lcid);
```

The nice way to do it could be a extension method to read the Custom Atribute from Enums:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueFromEnumMember<T>(string value) where T: Enum
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(EnumMemberAttribute)) as EnumMemberAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                if (attribute.Value == value)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == value)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException($"unknow value: {value}");
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var applications = _context.Application.Where(a => a.Language == EnumExtensions.GetValueFromEnumMember<Lcid>(lcid));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using **JsonStringEnumConverter()** you should have your enum type as a parameter:

```
[HttpGet("lcid/{lcid}")]
public async Task<ActionResult><IEnumerable<Application>>> GetApplicationByLcid([FromRoute]Lcid lcid)
```

But that will not work because *JsonStringEnumConverter* doesn't work with EnumMemberAttribute class.

In your case, you should write a custom JsonConverter that will use *EnumMemberAttribute*.

Here I found something might be useful for you:

[Enum value doesn't show EnumMember value on razor page ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414244/enum-value-doesnt-show-enummember-value-on-razor-page-asp-net-core-3-1)

[System.Text.Json: How do I specify a custom name for an enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059989/system-text-json-how-do-i-specify-a-custom-name-for-an-enum-value)

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31081#issuecomment-848697673